# TypeScript warns me that object is possible null immediately after null check. Why?

Tags: typescript

Code:

```
var iframeEl = document.getElementById('cases-iframe') as HTMLIFrameElement;
if (iframeEl) {
    iframeEl.contentWindow.postMessage(msg, '*');

}
```

Error:

```
[ts] Object is possibly 'null'.
(local var) iframeEl: HTMLIFrameElement
```

Why do I get this error when I have an if statement protecting against null? And how do I get around this error?

Comment: I misunderstood the error message. if (iframeEl && iframeEl.contentWindow) solved the problem

Comment: I too misunderstood the error message. I fixed it by using "?"  i.e,
`iframeEl.contentWindow?.postMessage(msg, '*');`